# Pressure gradients in Darcy's law for multiphase flows

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am learning Darcy's law for multiphase flows and I am confused about the pressure gradient.
When I was studying through the guidebook for （Pruess et al，1991, 1999, 2004）, it mentions that the liquid or gas pressure gradient is equal to the reference pressure（it says general the gas pressure） minus the capillary pressure, and I'm wondering what that means? Is this an approximation?[image]
I thought the pressure gradient was supposed to consist of the gas phase pressure minus the liquid static pressure minus the capillary pressure[image]
Maybe you can tell the meaning of the "reference phase" and why it can be like this way.I would like to know how to calculate the Darcy velocity for the wetted and non-wetted phases.
I would greatly appreciate it if anybody could give me some tips.

Thanks，

Luo